# Full Page and Skrollr incompatibility - slider site with the fixed objects attached to scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, parallax, skrollr, fullpage.js

I have to finish some project with my own ideas.

[Here is the video where You can see all wanted features and behaviors.](http://youtube.com/watch?v=lNZzJ_KCfKs)

Here is Work in Progress version made by guys from company where I'm learning: podpiwekjedrzej.com.

[Here is my Work in Progress current version.](http://web4u.rzeszow.pl/podpiwek/)

I need to make these effects from video above with my own ideas and choosen tools:
I have found FullPage.js for vertical and horizontal scrolling full screen slider-site.
For scrolled objects I have found Skrollr.js.

**Now:**

Without FullPage.js, Skrollr is working good.
On tablet with Android my current version is working, on pc is working just when i resize browser window to very small size, but then it's working only with keyboard.
I need also make an animated movement of menu - what tool is good for this?
All must be responsive.

I can't go forward with this project, beacause the key features are stopping me.

I'm just starting to learn about jQuery and JS, so I can't make self-written code for this yet.

Please help.

Comment: Hi, I have a very similar project. Could you give me an idea on how you did it in the end? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used skrollr.js but you can take a look at other pages using paralax and fullpage such as http://www.saltaboombox.com.ar/ to take ideas or to see how they have done it.

The problem with fullpage and some paralax plugins is that when using fullpage.js you are not actually scrolling but changing the `top` property of the site (or adding a css3 translade3d effect).

Anyway, I would recommend you to add the scripts between `<head>` and `</head>`. Fullpage operates over the body and the way to avoid problems is having all of the scripts in the header.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I won't be using Skrollr. Just FullPage.